# When WebDriver is an interface why in Java Doc it is mentioned as a class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

While I was reading Java doc for web driver it was mentioned as follows:

> public interface WebDriver extends SearchContext The main interface to
>   use for testing, which represents an idealized web browser.
>   The methods in this **class** fall into three categories: Control of
>   the browser itself Selection of WebElements Debugging aids Key methods
>   are get(String), which is used to load a new web page and the  various
>   methods similar to findElement(By), which is used to find 
>   WebElements.
>
> Currently, you will need to instantiate implementations of this
>   **class**  directly. It is hoped that you write your tests against this interface so that you may "swap in" a more fully featured browser
>   when there is a  requirement for one.

How can they mention an interface as a class? Then how the statement "you will need to instantiate implementations of this **class** 
    directly" is valid in any way.

Link: [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)